# Append to array within a struct Swift in Xcode

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, append, mutating-function

I want to insert an item into an array within a struct. I have a class Food

```
class Food {
      var name: String
      var category: String
    }
```

It's been initialized. I created a struct to contain the different food items into groups and placed that struct in an array.

```
 struct Group {
      var title: String
      var foods: [Food]

    mutating func add(food: Food) {
      foods.append(food)
    }

var groups = [Group]()
```

both variables are initialized, however it seems like the mutating func isn't working. When I try to add a new food item like so:

```
let newFood = Food(name: "Banana", category: "Fruit")
let foodType = newFood.category

for group in groups {
  if foodType == group.title {
     // this is what isn't working
     group.add(food: newFood)
} else {
   let tempGroup = Group(title: foodType, foods: [newFood])
   groups.append(tempGroup)
}
```

I get an error on the line directly under the comment `//this is what isn't working`  saying "group is a let constant and cannot be mutated". But I thought I solved that by making `mutating func add(food: Food)`.

What can I do to be able to append the newFood item to the correct section in the groups array?

Comment: `group` is a local copy. You could make it mutable by saying `for var group in groups`, but that still won't help. Your mutations will only effect the local mutable copy. You need to iterate by indices, so you could do `groups[i].add(food: newFood)`

Comment: I would actually suggest you use a `[String: [Food]]` rather than a `[Group]`. You'll find it easier for lookup

Comment: Would the dictionary ` [String: [Food]] ` work to populate a tableView?

Answer (score 0):

You are using local copy in for loop. Instead of that you can you indices.

```
struct Group {
  var title: String
  var foods: [Food]

  mutating func add(food: Food) {
    foods.append(food)
  }
}

var groups = [Group]()

for i in 0..<groups.count {
    if foodType == groups[i].title {
        groups[i].add(food: newFood)
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. Even with the correction I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

The 'group' declared in your for-loop is not the same instance in your 'groups' array. It's just a constant copy of the element you'd like to modify. Because struct Group is a 'Value Type', not a 'Reference Type'.